# external style for firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

my asp.net website has 2 stylesheet ,one is for chrome and another is for other browser. now my website template not show correctly in firefox; I tryed this code on stylesheet:

@-moz-document url-prefix(){
     firefox style goes here
    }
but when I copy my codes into:

```
 .leftarrowclass{
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    }
     @-moz-document url-prefix(){
     .leftarrowclass{
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    }
}
```

there is some error whit red color in css file. how can I define an external stylesheet for firefox like this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/chrome" href="css/avachr.css"/>
```

Comment: _“one is for chrome and another is for other browser”_ – _why_? There should rarely be a need to serve different stylesheets to Chrome and Firefox, those two being among the most standard-compliant browsers out there.

Comment: @CBroe : I want to do this, but don't know how~

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `temp` and use it as -

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
    li{ color: red; }
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipaks2011/MwT4y/1/)**